# Is it possible to exclude every user's personal documents in a SOQL query?

Tags: soql

It's relatively straight forward to exclude the current user's personal documents, but what about excluding all personal documents, i.e. `SELECT ... FROM Document WHERE FolderId != <any User Id>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work?

```
[
    SELECT Id, Name
    FROM Document
    WHERE FolderId IN (SELECT Id FROM Folder)
]
```

Comment: Seems to do the trick, my only concern is the performance as the number of folders increases, but I can't seem to think of a better way to produce this result.